# Python rolling forecast update lags

Tags: python

I would like to implement an OLS with a `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`.

I have a time series with 100 data points and the respective data.

My overall goal is to forecast the next 6 weeks. I have in x_train multiple explaining variables for my output. These include for example the date, the month and, amongst others, my lag variables. I have checked the significance of lags with the autocorrelation plot and it told me, lags 1-12 are significant, so 12 explaining variables are these 12 lags.

I have created 12 lag variables:

```
lag_variables=pd.concat([data.shift(1), data.shift(2),...., data.shift(12)]
```

These lag variables are 12 columns in my x_train dataframe, from which I choose my features.

However, if I want to forecast 6 data points, I need to update my lags.
Because for example for week 5, I don't have any lags 1-4, because I don't know them at the time of my forecast. For week 1 I know the lags 1-12, for week 2 I know the lags 2-12, and so on.

Python gives me now an error, since my x_train contains nan values, since I dont know all lags.

So my idea was, to forecast each week individually, so firstly I forecast week 1. Then, after I have forecasted week 1, I have the real value for week 1, and I can update my lags for week 2 with the real value. I am basically doing a rollig forecast with lags.

I have tried the following:

```
hist_x_train=[x for x in x_train]
hist_x_test=[x for x in x_test]
hist_y_train=[x for x in y_train]
hist_y_test=[x for x in y_test]

predictions=list()

for t in range(len(x_test)):
    model=best_praams   #gridsearch before the loop, chosses best parameter
    model.fit(hist_x_train, hist_y_train)
    y_pred=model.predict(hist_x_test[t])
    predictions.append(y_pred)
    hist_x_train.append(hist_x_test[t])
    hist_y_train.append(y_pred)
    print(y_test[t]) # this is my actual real value for that period; I don't     
   # know how to update this in x_train, so it shows up as a lag
```

Technically, the rolling forecast works like that if i don't have any lags in my x_train, but I don't know how to deal with the lags.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am little confused can you elaborate more.  Maybe you can give examples of what you are hoping to do?  Are you trying to test your data or are you just trying to predict variables?  Is your model trained on lag variables?  What is the overall goal of what you are doing here?  Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it becomes clear. I would be really great to get an answear, since I am a little lost.

Comment: I think I understand now.  You won't have all the lag variables as you progress into the future.  It sounds like you don't want to use your predictions as lags either.  If that is the case you will need to create different models for different subsets of lag variables.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I would create 6 different Dataframes with the lags, and then gave 6 different x_train and x_test variables?

Comment: You would have the same training data for the most part, you would just need to train the data to predict different Y values.  For example, lets say you have lag variables for 12 weeks, you train that data to predict the next week y_1, the week after that y_2 and so on.  Each y would be using the same lag variables but you would have a different target you are training on.  This way you could train models to predict a few weeks into the future rather than just the first week.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the train data with the predictions result in cascading errors which makes the next predictions almost constant or zero after some time, this should be avoided. Instead forecast for the next 6 weeks at one shot, or use multiple models (6 models here) to predict for the next 6 weeks, arrange your y_labels (y_1, y_2..... y_6) such that y_1 is lagged by 1 week, and y_2 by 2 weeks, and so on. and train then accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I did not want to use the predictions as lags, I want to use the real values. How do I forecast the next 6 weeks at one shot if my lags 1, 2, 3, 4 are significant? Because for week 5, I do not have the lags 1,2,3,4 since I don't know the real values at the time of the foreacst. This is my problem